# Python Pandas Dataframes comparison on 2 columns (with where clause)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck on particluar python question here. I have 2 dataframes **DF1** and **DF2**. In both, I have 2 columns **pID** and **yID** (which are not indexed, just default). I'm look to add a column **Found** in **DF1** where the respective values of columns (**pID** and **yID**) were found in **DF2**. Also, I would like to zone in on just values in **DF2** where **aID** == 'Text'.

I believe the below gets me the 1st part of this question; however, I'm unsure how as to incorporate the **where**.

```
DF1['Found'] = (DF1[['pID', 'yID']] == DF2[['pID','yID']]).all(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

Suggestions or answers would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subset the second dataframe containing `aID == 'Text'` to get a reduced `DF` from which select those portions of columns to be compared against the first dataframe.

Use [`DF.isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if the values that are present under these column names match or not. And, `.all(axis=1)` returns `True` if both the columns happen to be `True`, else they become `False`. Convert the boolean series to integers via `astype(int)` and assign the result to the new column, *`Found`*.

```
df1_sub = df1[['pID', 'yID']]
df2_sub = df2.query('aID=="Text"')[['pID', 'yID']]
df1['Found'] = df1_sub.isin(df2_sub).all(axis=1).astype(int)
df1
```

[image]

**Demo `DF's` used:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(pID=[1,2,3,4,5],
                       yID=[10,20,30,40,50]))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(pID=[1,2,8,4,5],
                       yID=[10,12,30,40,50],
                       aID=['Text','Best','Text','Best','Text']))
```

---

If it does not matter where those matches occur, then merge the two dataframes on `'pID', 'yID'` common columns as the key by considering the bigger `DF's` index (`right_index=True`) as the new index axis that needs to be emitted and aligned after the merge operation is over.

Access these indices which indicate matches found and assign the value, 1 to a new column named *`Found`* while filling it's missing elements with 0's throughout.

```
df1.loc[pd.merge(df1_sub, df2_sub, on=['pID', 'yID'], right_index=True).index, 'Found'] = 1
df1['Found'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

`df1` should be modifed accordingly post the above steps.

Comment: An answer was truly what I was looking for. thank you. Also, thank you for taking the time to explain what each method would return.

Comment: Will both the size and order have an effect on this result? (DF1 is larger and both are not in order).. For instance, I'm seeing a return of False in 'Found' where the combination of 'pID' and 'yID' is present in both DF1 and DF2.

Comment: It would definitely have an impact as the matches occur only if their index and values under the column names are aligned correctly. From the documentation page - *If values is a DataFrame, then both the index and column labels must match.*

Comment: I've updated my post to include that condition as well.